# Regex - Named Group inside of a named group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've created a regex that matches this the URL below but now I want to match the whole URL, capture it in a named group and capture the uid of the URL in another named group.

The example:

```
<"http://www.accounts.com/support/uid=swg1PM80378">
```

The expected outcome:

```
first group: http://www.accounts.com/support/uid=swg1PM80378
second group: swg1PM80378
```

My regex so far:

```
<"(?<link>.*(?<id>NOTHING IN HERE YET))">
```

With this regex I can match the whole URL and capture it in the named group  but I want to expand the regex's functionality to also capture the uid of the link and capture it in the second group named

I've used the site https://regexr.com/ to create the regex, maybe it'll be of help.

Comment: You forgot to show us the pattern you created.

Comment: @Rabinzel oh yeah, now it should be added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\"(?P<link>.*(?P<id>(?<=uid=).*))\"
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/bz1hgL/1)

---

`\"` - match `"`

- `(?P<link>.*)` - Match any number of characters into named group `link`

  - `(?P<id>(?<=uid=).*)` - Match any number of characters preceded witch `uid=` into named group `link`
- `\"` - match `"`